# Dynamic Variable Compilation in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, angular

I need to achieve dynamic variable compilation inside HTML Template using Angular 7.

Here is my sample code:

app.component.ts:

```
username = 'User Name';
sampleData = "This is my <strong>{{username}}</strong>";
```

app.component.html:

```
<div [innerHtml]="sampleData"></div>
```

But, still the output is

```
This is my {{username}}.
```

My Expected output is,

```
This is my UserName
```

The same feature can be achieved in Angular 1 using `$compile`. Please let me know how to achieve this in Angular 7

Comment: May be this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
username = 'User Name';
sampleData = "This is my <strong>" + this.username + "</strong>";
```

As per your comment, for dynamic tdata you can do this:

```
username = 'User Name';
sampleData = "This is my {{username}}";

ngOnInit() {
   this.sampleData = this.sampleData.replace("{{username}}", `<strong> ${this.username} </strong>`)
}
```

Comment: The variable sampleData is dynamic and will be stored in a separate json. Hence i need to compile it in html instead of direct data interpolation.

Comment: @GaneshBabu you can complile your string as required in `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-template and create a local reference of it and use it with ngTemplateOutlet wherein you can pass in the dynamic content.

HTML (template)

```
<ng-template #temp let-item>
  <div> This is my variable <strong>{{ item }}</strong> which is dynmically parsed. </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="temp; context: { $implicit: name }"></ng-container>
```

Typescript

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

Check the stackblitz demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lec12u

Comment: We need "<div> This is my variable <strong>{{ item }}</strong> which is dynmically parsed. </div>" to be stored in a variable inside component. The above solution doesn't work for that case